# Calling Chrome web browser from the webbrowser.get() in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, browser, ubuntu-11.04

How I should call webbrowser.get() function so I open the chrome web browser? I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and Python version 2.7. 
Using webbrowser.get('chrome') yields an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quick workaround is to make Chrome the default browser in your system and then use simply webbrowser.get(). I've just checked that on ubuntu 10.10 and it worked just fine.

**EDIT**

Just reviewed the code of /usr/lib/python2.6/webbrowser.py. You should do like this:

```
In [5]: webbrowser.get('/usr/bin/google-chrome %s').open('http://google.com')
Created new window in existing browser session.
Out[5]: True

In [6]: webbrowser.get('firefox %s').open('http://google.com')
Out[6]: True
```

I.e. having '%s' in get()'s parameter is the key feature.

Comment: yeah it could work, but the application that I'm writing requires I call the browser that way. I'm writing a small utility script that invokes a browser user chooses with some urls already loaded in the tabs.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Although I need to refine my program a bit. I'm using a for-loop to supply the urls for all new tabs, but it appears, chrome waits until one tab is closed to open the other tab.

Comment: Perhaps try the open_new_tab() method?

Comment: Cross platform version would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

for mac, do this 
`webbrowser.get("open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s").open("http://google.com")`