# IPython - ipython_notebook_config.py missing

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

When I'm creating a profile, only 2 config files are created, instead of 5.

```
ipython profile create test_3

[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'/root/.ipython/profile_test_3/ipython_config.py'
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'/root/.ipython/profile_test_3/ipython_kernel_config.py'
```

I have 2 versions of python installed, 2.6.6 and 2.7. I have created an alias for python to use /usr/bin/python2.7

I have installed both easy_install and pip

The full list of packages installed with pip:

alabaster (0.7.6)
appnope (0.1.0)
Babel (2.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
certifi (2015.4.28)
decorator (4.0.2)
Django (1.8.3)
docutils (0.12)
funcsigs (0.4)
functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
gnureadline (6.3.3)
ipykernel (4.0.3)
ipyparallel (4.0.0)
**ipython (4.0.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)**
ipywidgets (4.0.2)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jsonschema (2.5.1)
jupyter-client (4.0.0)
jupyter-core (4.0.2)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.4.3)
mistune (0.7)
mock (1.3.0)
nbconvert (4.0.0)
nbformat (4.0.0)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (4.0.1)
numpy (1.9.2)
numpydoc (0.5)
pandas (0.16.2)
path.py (7.6)
pbr (1.4.0)
pexpect (3.3)
pickleshare (0.5)
pip (7.1.0)
ptyprocess (0.5)
Pygments (2.0.2)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
pyreadline (2.0)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
pytz (2015.4)
pyzmq (14.7.0)
qtconsole (4.0.0)
requests (2.7.0)
scikit-learn (0.16.1)
scipy (0.16.0)
setuptools (18.1)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.9.0)
snowballstemmer (1.2.0)
Sphinx (1.3.1)
sphinx-rtd-theme (0.1.8)
terminado (0.5)
testpath (0.2)
tornado (4.2.1)
traitlets (4.0.0)

Am I missing something? Can someone link me to a ipython_notebook_config.py file so i can use that in the default profile? Would that be wrong to enforce?

I have added a ipython_notebook_config.py from web and edit it..and it seems it's ignoring it..I'm specifying port 8888 and it's listing port 8889. Furthermore I can't connect to that notebook.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can skip creating a profile and pass the parameters directly:
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser --ip='*' --port=8889" $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark

Comment: This doesn't address the issue(s) in the question...what can/should he (viz. I) have done to create an ipython_notebook_config.py file, or is it no longer necessary, or has it been replaced by the ipython_kernel_config.py file?

Answer (score 10):

Things have changed in jupyter since "the big switch", where notebook configurations have migrated to the .jupyter folder. If you already have an existing ipython notebook configuration, try doing:

```
jupyter migrate
```

if your notebook config is missing (which was my case when starting ipython to create a profile), you can generate a jupyter config with the following:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

this should create a ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py file with relevant notebook settings ready to be uncommented/modified such as ports and passwords.

It should be noted for profiles, jupyter no longer supports multiple profiles, but they can be referenced via command line (see http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html#profiles for more info)

documentation: http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html