# Run jupyter notebook in incognito window

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

On executing the command ***jupyter notebook***, notebook opens on Mozilla Firefox.

How to open notebook on **incognito mode of Mozilla Firefox** from command line?

Answer (score 3):

In your config add the following to set the default browser to a private firefox (adapted from [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/83035/webbrowser.register) and parameters from [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)):

`jupyter_notebook_config.py`

```py
[...]
## Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the notebook.
#  If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the `webbrowser`
#  standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER environment
#  variable to override it.
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('private_firefox', None, webbrowser.get('"' + 'path/to/firefox' +'" -private %s'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'private_firefox'
[...]
```

where `path/to/firefox` would be something like one of these

- `/usr/bin/firefox` for Linux (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35229604/))
- `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox` for macOS (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16704588/))
- `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe` for Windows (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15632663/))

---

**note:**
Other browsers like Chrome (`"...\\chrome.exe" --incognito`as in the [source](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/83035/webbrowser.register)) would work analogously, I suppose. I have not tested others. Feel free to comment, if there are any hurdles.

Answer (score 0):

Typically Jupyer opens on http://localhost:8888 all you need to do is copy that url and open it yourself in an incognito Firefox session.

Comment: I don't think there is a way since jupyter just opens in your computers default browser - how come it needs to be a command line based solution?

Answer (score 0):

On Safari, if the focus is on an incognito window, the notebook will open automatically in it.