# Opening Jupyter Notebook in a separate window

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

Jupyter notebooks, used with or without anaconda opens up in a browser window, now how do I change this to a spearate window, like **whenever I open jupyter, it should be opened in a separate, new browser window.**

If there is a way, it'd be super useful as I generally have tons of tabs opened in current window.

Thanks in advance if there's a way:)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) there is a `NotebookApp.webbrowser_open_new` option available and setting that to 1 should open jupyter in a new window.

I tried this and unfortunately it did not work, not sure why (it does say in the docs that this may not work)

What ended up working for me was adding this to my config

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register("private_chrome", None, webbrowser.get('"' + 'path\\to\\chrome.exe' + '" -incognito %s'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'private_chrome'
```

Replace the string with path to your chrome.exe (using an r string didn't work for me so I would recommend using double backslashes \ if you're on windows ofc)

[Thanks to gr4nt3d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813292/11993580)