# How to default open Jupyter Notebook in incognito mode (Chrome)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

No matter what I do, jupyter notebook always opens in chrome non-incognito mode.
This is my jupyter_notebook_config.py file

```
## Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the notebook.
#  If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the `webbrowser`
#  standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER environment
#  variable to override it.
#  Default: ''

import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('incognito-chrome',None, webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito"))
c.ServerApp.browser = 'incognito-chrome'
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run jupyter notebook in incognito window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787973/run-jupyter-notebook-in-incognito-window)

Comment: @Sys.Overdrive that was the first stack overflow question i opened. and i copied all the code from it and just tweaked it to be google chrome incognito. however, it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Another way of opening an incognito chrome window is as below:

```
import webbrowser as wb
jUrl = 'http://localhost:8888' #Default jupyter host
incongnito_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito'
wb.get(incongnito_path).open_new(jUrl)
```

This works for me!

Comment: hi, so let me get this clear, there's no way to configure the file so that the browser opened is chrome incognito? because the solution you gave me basically opened a chrome incognito tab, on top of another, regular chrome tab (because the default configurations were never changed)

Comment: @sirj Yes as of now this is the best thing you can do. But i will try in my local to see if the jupyter-settings can be tweaked to make it work on jupyter app level, will keep you posted here.