# How to open a url through python code on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, python-webbrowser

I want to open a url through python code on mac osx. I am using safari. I tried `webbrowser.open(url,new=1,autoraise=True)` , `webbrowser.open(url)`, `webbrowser.open_new(url)`,  `webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)`. Sometimes, a new tab will open, Sometimes it will not, if already four-five tabs are opened. I want to make it work on all browsers like safari, chrome etc.

Comment: Have you tried the methods [outlined here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6042407/1681480) to specify the browser?

Comment: yes, but I want to open a url by default browser. Suppose, chrome, mozilla is not installed, then it should work with safari.

Comment: The default is to use the default browser. I think you should post some code where you can reproduce "This one opens as expected" and "this one doesn't". It is impossible to debug when you say it works sometimes. The library is cross platform, so all the examples in the other questions where this has been asked should be relevant. According to one of them chrome will specifically wait until you close a tab that has been opened in this way.

Answer (score 5):

To add something to the previous answer... I had the same question, but wanted to open a local (SVG) file in Google Chrome.
The solution I found ([here](http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/creating-and-viewing-html-files-with-python)) was

```
    if platform == "darwin":  # check if on OSX
        file_location = "file:///" + file_location
    webbrowser.get().open(file_location, new=new)
```

This works for me on OSX 10.10.4.