# How do I open a url through the designated default browser in python-3?

Tags: python-webbrowser, python-3.9

So I'm writing a program with python-3.9 that's supposed to open the designated default browser on Windows. The problem is that every time I run the program, it always opens the Internet Explorer window and not the designated default browser. I use the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) library and my code goes like this:

```
import webbrowser

browser = webbrowser.get('windows-default')
browser.open_new(link)
```

The `link` variable contains the url of the site I want to open. Based on the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) documentation, the code above should open the Windows default browser but it doesn't do anything when I run it. I also tried changing `'windows-default'` to `'chrome'` or `'google-chrome'` which was supposed to open Google Chrome but it just returns this error:

```
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

I changed my code to `webbrowser.open_new(link)` and it opens the url in Internet Explorer but who would willingly use IE these days? I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042335/calling-chrome-web-browser-from-the-webbrowser-get-in-python) solution from almost 10 years ago as it was the only available solution I could find but still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `webbrowser.get()` instead of `webbrowser.get('windows-default')`? According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html), that should return the default browser.

```py
import webbrowser

browser = webbrowser.get()
browser.open_new(link)
```

Comment: Yep. I tried it already and it's doing nothing. The terminal says it's doing its job but there's nothing happening.

Comment: What does it list for the result of `webbrowser.get()`? Also, for the solution that you linked, you tried the location of the chrome binary on your system, right?

Comment: Yeah I tried it. I'm actually using the code as a part of a function called when you click a button. When I click it, there's no response from the "Run" window. No errors either but nothing's happening.